# How to detect DVD drive name with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

i create an cross platform electron application for playing video from dvd (in offline mode).
when user inserted DVD in the driver , the xml file (list of videos url and details) should load from DVD.

so for video url i need access to dvd driver name.

```
<video src="file:/video/video.mp4">
```

*file:/ should be dvd drive name.

there was a npm package but not working
https://www.npmjs.com/package/drivelist

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? Could you show your implementation of this package ? Not sure you can access DVD file directly from the view with src attribute..

Comment: sorry, my mean this package just return system drivers. not supported dvd-drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was another package return system volume as dvd-rom.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskinfo

this code return the dvd drive name, but i'm not sure its good idea or not.

```
var d = require('diskinfo');
var cddisk;
d.getDrives(function (err, aDrives) {
  for (var i = 0; i < aDrives.length; i++) {
    if (aDrives[i].available == 0) {
      cddisk = aDrives[i].mounted;
      console.log(cddisk);
    }
  }

});
```

also this package not supported in mac.

Comment: Glad to see you persevere on solving your issue, but you should really add these informations in the body of your question rather than in an answer that didn't answer the question.

Comment: @TGrif thanks for your help, i'm new :) sorry about that